# Qt - Widget slides on screen over all other widgets

Tags: qt, user-interface, flyout

I'm trying to create a menu flyout similar to how Adobe XD does it (an example is in this [video](https://youtu.be/cryJrvq1g6c?t=18) at 20s). Does anyone know the correct approach to doing this with the QT framework?

Comment: A `QML` [`Drawer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks :)